# Failed to load the vue route component

Tags: vue.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmmLn.png)

This problem has bothered me for a long time. I do not understand why the route component cannot be loaded when loading . I tried to check the path, but it didn't work

Comment: There seems to be an error with your imports, are the file paths right?

Comment: Did you try without the @ alias ?

Comment: it might help if you could share your project's folder structure